# jQuery Cropper to PHP Imagick: equivalent of imagecopyresampled in Imagick

Tags: php, resize, crop, imagick

I am using jQuery Cropper to get the parameters for cropping the image that I do in PHP. I would like to use `Imagick` but I can't understand what the equivalent of `imagecopyresampled` is.

[cropper parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J035t.jpg)

Comment: Please explain in detail what you want to achieve, what you tried, and which is the exact problem you found. In the meantime, take a look to the imagemagick documentation: https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php

Comment: Assuming that you have the paramters you want in jQuery, which is Javascript on the web browser, how do you intend to send those paramters back to PHP on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Currently through Cropper's `getData()` function I get these parameters:

```
$dst_x = offset left of the cropped area
$dst_y = offset top of the cropped area
$dst_width = the width of the cropped area
$dst_height = the height of the cropped area.
```

I pass these parameters through ajax to PHP.

Using `imagecopyresampled()`, I can get the same cropped area via Cropper.
Let's say I want to get a final 240x400 image.

```
$crop_width = 240; 
$crop_height = 400; 

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($crop_width, $crop_height);
imagecopyresampled($new_image, $source_image, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $crop_width, $crop_height, $dst_width, $dst_height);
```

But I want to use PHP Imagick for image processing but I can't find a function similar to `imagecopyresampled()` to get the same effect.